# Induced functor on slice category.

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ be to categories, $F: \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{D}$ a functor and $X \in \mathbf{C}$ an object. My task is to construct an induced functor $F/X: \mathbf{C}/X \to \mathbf{D}/FX$

My first question is if $\mathbf{D}/FX$ is a typo, shouldn't it be just $\mathbf{D}/X$? If so, what restrictions do I have in my construction regarding the word "induced",does this mean I have to construct a functor that inherits the properties of $F$ as a functor?

Comment: No it's not a typo. $FX$ is an object in $D$ as it must be. If you write out what the slice category looks like, then it will be obvious what the induced functor must be.

Comment: @Chilango ah ok, so $FX$ is just the image of $X$ under $F$?

Comment: @category, yes. Read it as $F(X)$ instead, if that helps.